# Perl: referencing/blessing question

Tags: perl, pass-by-reference, tie, bless

The idea is to implement a class that gets a list of [arrays, Thread::Conveyor queues and other stuff] in a TIEHASH constructor,

```
use AbstractHash; 
tie(%DATA, 'AbstractHash', \@a1, \@a2, \$tcq);
```

What is a correct way to pass object references (like mentioned [Thread::Conveyor](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Thread%3a%3aConveyor) objects) thus array references into constructor, so it can access the objects? Any cases when a passed object should be blessed?

Comment: Did you try the code example you included?  Did you get the desired results?

Comment: And, what would an object be if it wasn't blessed? :)

Comment: lol @OMG_peanuts)  should do &JohnTheBaptist{} that will traverse all the scopes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, objects are not objects unless they're `bless`-ed.

That said, the constructor argument would simply be an arrayref of `Thread::Conveyor` objects:

```
my $data = AbstractHash->tie ( \@a1, \@a2, \$tcq );
```

where the constructor is defined in the `AbstractHash` package:

```
sub tie {

    my $class = shift;  # Implicit variable, don't forget

    my $data = {
                 someArray => +shift,
                 queues    => +shift,
                 someValue => +shift,
               };

    # $data starts life as a hashref, make it an 'AbstractHash'

    bless $data, $class; # $data is no longer a hashref
    return $data;        # AbstractHash object returned
}
```